# Godot opens properly, but window wont resize for some reason

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, chromebook

So, I went through the lengthy, headache-filled ('cause I'm kind of a linux noob) process of installing Godot and making it into an executable. Accessing the properly-working file through Crouton seems to present a single problem to me. I don't even know the proper keyboard shortcut/command/operation to resize Godot's window, which at the time is too small for work.  I see no part of the UI that can do that, so how exactly do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, changed my desktop environment to GNOME and updated to Bionic Beaver and everything works like a charm.